# Reading and writing pickles using Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pickle, bucket

I want to read an existing pickle (that contains a dictionary) which is stored in a folder inside a Google Cloud Bucket. Then update the pickle after performing some functions, which is equal to overwriting the pickle.

Traditionally I would do something like:

```
import pickle
# Read pickle:
pickle_in = open('dictionary.pickle','rb')
my_dictionary = pickle.load(pickle_in)
my_dictionary 

# MODIFY DICTIONARY BY, FOR EXAMPLE, ADDING NEW REGISTERS

# Overwrite pickle:
pickle_out = open('dictionary.pickle','wb') 
pickle.dump(my_modified_dictionary,pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Now I need to do something similar but on Google Cloud. So I need to change the path of the file and use cloudstorage.open():

```
import pickle
my_path = '/bucket_name/pickle_folder/my_dictionary.pickle'

# Read pickle:
pickle_in = cloudstorage.open(path,'r')
my_dictionary = pickle.load(pickle_in)
my_dictionary 

# MODIFY DICTIONARY BY, FOR EXAMPLE, ADDING NEW REGISTERS

# Overwrite pickle:
pickle_out = cloudstorage.open(path,'w') 
pickle.dump(my_modified_dictionary,pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Will this work? [cloudstorage.open()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open) seems to be the equivalent to open(). But I am not sure that if I specify the path when dumping the pickle will actually overwrite the pickle on the specified folder.

Comment: You are using a Python 2 library in App Engine which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 11):

The basic idea of doing read-modify-write from GCS is possible. You should be aware that this will not work well with concurrency - if a second process does a read before the the first writes back, then when the second process writes back it will lose the first process's changes. The best solution to this is to use a database rather than pickling to GCS.

In addition, be aware that [pickle is not secure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-interface), and you should not load pickles you didn't write.

If you do still want to use GCS for this you should use the [standard GCS client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries), something like:

```py
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.bucket('your-gcs-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('dictionary.pickle')
pickle_in = blob.download_as_string()
my_dictionary = pickle.loads(pickle_in)

# MODIFY DICTIONARY BY, FOR EXAMPLE, ADDING NEW REGISTERS

pickle_out = pickle.dumps(my_modified_dictionary)
blob.upload_from_string(pickle_out)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried it out and could pickle_in, but not pickle_out. Latter one gives the exception: ... Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported.  Can anybody help?

Comment: @4554888 This is probably happening because you are trying to pickle the `storage_client` (possible inside an array or even deep inside some dictionary or other object).  Make sure the parameter to `pickle.dumps` is plain-old-data.

Comment: @David Thank you , it works (I needed to blob.reload()  otherwise I got en erro: # Provided CRC32C \"Tsij4g==\" doesn't match calculated CRC32C \"hdZzGQ==\"."  )      Do you know how to change the name of the file in the bucket - currently, the old file is replaced. Can I use a brand-new file for the upload?

Comment: To use a different object name, just create a new blob object, e.g. `new_blob= bucket.blob('new_blob_name')` before `new_blob.upload_from_string(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit more pythonic solution that will also automatically close the filestreams for you:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pickle

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('your-gcs-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('dictionary.pickle')

d = {'a': 1, 'b':2}

# write
with blob.open(mode='wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(d, f)

# read
with blob.open(mode='rb') as f:
   d_reloaded = pickle.load(f)

print(d_reloaded)
```